# How do I remove ubuntu 12.04 completely

Tags: uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I completely remove Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92208/how-do-i-completely-remove-ubuntu)

Please help I have read through all possible option on getting this done and am getting nowhere fast. I need to completely remove ubuntu 12.04 and install win xp. It is not a dual boot system and the disk i am using is a torrent download so not automatically loading when the pc boots up.